# why jquery toggle() method doesnot work properly if page is not refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using following code i ma calling a modal window. I am using jquery .toggle() method to hide and show some portion of modal window based on a checkbox selection.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      function ShowSaveEventForm(start, end, allDay) {
            var month = start.getMonth() + 1 + "";
            if (month.length == 1) {
                month = "0" + month;
            }
            var date = start.getDate() + "";
            if (date.length == 1) {
                date = "0" + date;
            }
            var year = start.getFullYear();
            var hours = start.getHours();
            var sec = start.getSeconds();
            var msec = start.getMilliseconds();
            var stdate = new Date(year, month, date, hours, sec, msec);
            var sdate = year + "-" + month + "-" + date;
            var month = end.getMonth() + 1 + "";
            if (month.length == 1) {
                month = "0" + month;
            }
            var date = end.getDate() + "";
            if (date.length == 1) {
                date = "0" + date;
            }
            var year = end.getFullYear();
            var hours = end.getHours();
            var sec = end.getSeconds();
            var msec = end.getMilliseconds();
            var eddate = new Date(year, month, date, hours, sec, msec);
            var edate = year + "-" + month + "-" + date;
            $('#eventdate').val(sdate);
            $('#edate').val(edate);
            var acctype = $('input:radio[name=accesstype]:checked').val();
             if (acctype == 1) {
                $('#chose-multi').hide();
            }
            $("#check").click(function() {
               $("#stime").toggle();
                $("#etime").toggle();
             });
            $("#rstrcted").click(function() {
                $("#chose-multi").show();
            });
            $("#private").click(function() {
                $("#chose-multi").hide();
            });
            $("#public").click(function() {
                $("#chose-multi").hide();
            });
            $('#error-message').hide(); // hide the error message section
            $('#modal-form').modal('show');
        }
```

And my HTML code is

```
<div id="modal-form" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <center>     <h4 class="blue bigger">Create Event</h4></center>
            </div>
            <center>
                <div id="error-message" class="alert alert-danger col-xs-12" style="display:none; height:10%">
                    <!-- Place holder for errors -->

                </div>
            </center>

            <div class="modal-body overflow-visible">
                <div class="row" style="height:10%">
                    <div class="col-xs-12"> <!-- Start Col-->

                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-left">Event Type</td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-8">                                         
                                        <label>
                                            <input id="eventtype" type="radio" name="caltype" value="{{ constant('KonnectEz\\WebBundle\\Common\\CommonConstants::VALUE_FOR_HOLIDAY') }}"/>
                                            <span class="lbl"> Holiday</span>
                                        </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                                        
                                        <label>
                                            <input id="caltype" type="radio" name="caltype" value="{{ constant('KonnectEz\\WebBundle\\Common\\CommonConstants::VALUE_FOR_EVENT') }}" checked/>
                                            <span class="lbl"> Event</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-left">Name</td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-8" ><input id="name" type="text" name="eventname" value="" required /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-left">Description</td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-8" > <input id="desc" type="text" name="description" value=""/> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>

                                    <td class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-left">Event Start Date</td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-8"><input id="eventdate" type="text"   name="date"  value="yyyy-mm-dd" />                                      

                                    </td>
                                <tr>

                                    <td class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-left">Event End Date</td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-8"><input id="edate" type="text"   name="eventenddate"  value="yyyy-mm-dd" />                                   

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>   
                                    <td class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-left">Event Duration</td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-8"> 
                                        <div  class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input id="check" name="agrType-chk" type="checkbox" value="1" />
                                                <span class="lbl"> All Day </span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr id="stime">
                                    <td class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-left" id="time">Start Time</td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-8" > <input  type="text" name="stime" value="08:00" /> 

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr id="etime">
                                    <td class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-left" id="edtime">End Time</td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-8" id="etime"> <input  type="text" name="etime" value="18:00" />                                           
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>                                          
                                    <td class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-left">Access Type</td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-8"> 

                                        <label>
                                            <input id="public" name="accesstype" type="radio" value="{{ constant('KonnectEz\\WebBundle\\Common\\CommonConstants::VALUE_FOR_PUBLIC') }}" checked/>
                                            <span class="lbl"> Public </span>                                                
                                        </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                        <label>
                                            <input id="private" name="accesstype" type="radio" value="{{ constant('KonnectEz\\WebBundle\\Common\\CommonConstants::VALUE_FOR_PRIVATE') }}" />
                                            <span class="lbl"> Private </span>                                                
                                        </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                        <label>
                                            <input id="rstrcted" name="accesstype" type="radio" value="{{ constant('KonnectEz\\WebBundle\\Common\\CommonConstants::VALUE_FOR_RESTRICTED') }}" />
                                            <span class="lbl"> Restricted </span>                                                
                                        </label>

                                    </td>
                                </tr> 
                                <tr id="chose-multi">                                
                                    <td class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-left" >Select A Group:</td>
                                    <td class="col-sm-8" > 
                                       {# <div class="row">#}
                                        <div class="space-2"></div>
                                        <select multiple="" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8" id="selector" name="selector" >
                                                 {#<option value="0">Select Group</option>#}
                                      {% for group in groupList %}
                                            <option value="{{group.id}}">{{ group.name }}</option>
                                      {% endfor %}
                                        </select>                                  
                                       {# </div>  #}
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </table>   

                        </div>
                    </div>                 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="height:10%">
                <button id="save" class="btn btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">                    
                    Cancel
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="btnsubsave">                   
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>       
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But jquery .toggle() is not working properly on alternate times. Can anyone help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring following code out of the function `ShowSaveEventForm`

```
$("#check").click(function() {
    $("#stime").toggle();
    $("#etime").toggle();
});
$("#rstrcted").click(function() {
    $("#chose-multi").show();
});
$("#private").click(function() {
    $("#chose-multi").hide();
});
$("#public").click(function() {
    $("#chose-multi").hide();
});
```

So it is like following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#check").click(function() {
           $("#stime").toggle();
            $("#etime").toggle();
         });
        $("#rstrcted").click(function() {
            $("#chose-multi").show();
        });
        $("#private").click(function() {
            $("#chose-multi").hide();
        });
        $("#public").click(function() {
            $("#chose-multi").hide();
        });

function ShowSaveEventForm(start, end, allDay) {
        var month = start.getMonth() + 1 + "";
        if (month.length == 1) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
...
...
```